# Drop down of currency switcher always expanded after moving it to header?

Tags: magento2

When I move currency to header from top panel , the currency dropdown always visible , means I can see all my currency without clicking it : here is the image:

[image]

Here is my default.xml file code:

```
    <container name="header.row" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row">
        <container name="header.left" label="headerLeft" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-4 class1" />
        <container name="header.left1" label="headerLeft1" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-2 class2" />
        <container name="header.center" label="headerCenter" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-4 class3" />
        <container name="header.right" label="headerRight" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-2 class5" />
    </container>


</referenceContainer>

<move element="currency" destination="header.right" />
```

I need not show the list items with out clicking it?

Comment: Have you check magento console or log file? Is there any error?

Comment: Actually I Am a beginner , I checked var/log folder and its files, but I don't know how to check that.

Comment: You need to check Magento Root -> Var -> Log folder, what ever file there try to open that and check is that anything error mension there?

Comment: [2022-02-25 04:56:31] main.INFO: Item Magento_Backend::system_currency was removed [] []      - I can find out a line about currency.